# why change value in Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I face small puzzle problem in Laravel select query. It automatic change data type.

**When i use**

```
$data = Model::select('user_id AS id')->get();
```

data is `[{"id":3},{"id":4}] // not actual value`

**But When i use** (only change Alias **id** to **ID**)

```
$data = Model::select('user_id AS ID')->get();
```

data is `[{"ID":"03"},{"ID":"04"}] // actual value`

what is the problem

Comment: I have tried with various of my models to reproduce this but can't. Can you share your model code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Laravel automatically casts the `id` field to an integer, as it will be the primary key of your model.

> Primary Keys
>
> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a protected $primaryKey property to override this convention.
>
> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an int automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must set the public $incrementing property on your model to false. If your primary key is not an integer, you should set the protected $keyType property on your model to string.

[laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)

If you wish to set the property `ID` to an integer, you can use Eloquent's Attribute Casting:

[laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)